# Painting/doodling on my white Hydroflask

Tags: material-selection, paint, tool-selection, varnish, markers

I'm planning to make multiple small doodles of baby pandas on my new hydroflask. But I'm afraid if I choose a wrong tool to do it, the dishwasher may spoil it. Can you please advice on the following:

1. What kind of paint to use to keep it dishwasher-safe?
2. If markers or marker-pens are better than paints, what type/brand should I look for?
3. Will decoupage glue that I use as varnish keep the bottle from getting ruined in dishwasher?

Comment: What material is the bottle made from? Does it have an existing coating?

Comment: the shell of this stainless steel bottle is coated with quality color last molding powder, a kind of thermoset polymer.

Comment: I know that Sharpie is variable in the dishwasher depending on the surface.  I use a (usually blue) one to label boxes in the freezer, and on smooth plastic it fades around the second wash, handily erasing it in my case.  On textured plastic it lasts far longer.  Other marker pen brands have been comparable - some washing off quicker, others slower, but none truly permanent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](https://feelingnifty.com/hydro-flask-painting-diy-tutorial/), you can use acrylic paints to decorate your flask, and then seal it with a dishwasher-safe sealant.

For painting you can use regular acrylic paints, and for doodling you can use acrylic paint markers.
I suggest to opt for higher quality products, as they will have a higher amount of pigment and improve the coverage on your flask.

There are paint markers available that are dishwasher safe (like, for example, [these ones](https://www.slumpys.com/Fusible-Art-Glass/Marabu-Pens)).
For other products you might have to use a sealant.

In the linked article, the flasks were painted with regular acrylic paints, and afterwards a dishwasher-safe Mod Podge sealant was used to prevent if from peeling and chipping. This seems to work fine, but remember that this particular sealant is not food grade. However, as long as it is not applied to a surface where it will get into contact with food or your lips, this should be a safe choice. You might also be able to find sealants that are both dishwasher-safe and food grade.
Make sure to heed the drying time, though, to guarantee the highest level of inertness.